# javascript parameter passing

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that takes a value. THe value is begin taken from a dropdownlist. I am unable to pass the value to the function and would like to know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

JS Function

```
Puma.selectEvent = function(year) {

        var year = year;
        select the event
}
```

Event on dropdownlist change. The sYear, sMonth, and sSeason are dropdownlist names. The "Puma" is not important.

```
onChange=Puma.selectEvent(sYear.value);
```

Comment: Please show us the full code - to which onchange do you add the function?

Comment: You've verified that accessing `sYear` directly, instead of getting by name or id, is working for you? Or you've already retrieved the DOM elements?

Comment: I'm sorry, I put too many variable. It is the onchange to the sYear dropdownlist. I've tried getElementId, but that didn't work either.

Comment: If you need to pass the value of the drop down being changed simply have `onChange="Puma.selectEvent(this.value);"`

Comment: @ShadowWizard It did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are misunderstanding how event hookups work.  Let's start with this line

```
onChange=Puma.selectEvent(sYear.value);
```

You probably think that is binding the Puma.selectEvent handler to onChange event ... but you'd be wrong.  If you wanted to do that, you'd write:

```
onChange=Puma.selectEvent;
```

ie. you'd set the onChange to the "selectEvent" function itself.  What you were doing was setting onChange to the *output of* a call to selectEvent; in other words, what selectEvent returns.

Second, let's look at this line:

```
Puma.selectEvent = function(year) {
```

You might think that that will result in you getting the year (from the select) passed in to your function, but you'd be mistaken.  ALL event handlers get passed an *event* object (often called "e").  Now, that event has properties (like target and currentTarget) which you can use to get to the select's value, but you need to do something like `e.target.value` to do so.

Comment: so how would I go about passing the value to from the dropdown to the function without the parameter? The functions are in two different files.

Comment: I'm a little unclear: what element are you binding the onChange to?

Comment: @MasterP: If I understood you right,
`onChange = function() {
    Puma.selectEvent(sYear.value);
}`
could do the trick.

Comment: Ah, thanks rhino I wasn't grokking that that's what OP was looking for.  If you want to get fancy, libraries that offer "binding" allow you to pre-set arguments to a function.  For instance, using Underscore you can do `var selectEventWithYear = _.bind(selectEvent, null, sYear.value);` to make a version of selectEvent that always has its first argument set to `sYear.value`

Comment: @rhino I tried that, but the debugging process did not go to the SelectEvent function.

Comment: @MasterP: Where do you perform the assignment? Perhaps you're embedding the JS code within HTML? If so, see the following: http://jsfiddle.net/dqfbd/1/ (by the way, missing quotes could be your problem if you're doing it this way).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with the code you posted:

```
Puma.selectEvent = function (year) {
    // year is a parameter, you should not overwrite it
    var year = year; // get rid of this line
    select the event
}

// this line is EXECUTING Puma.selectEvent(sYear.value)
// and assigning it's return value to the onchange property
onChange=Puma.selectEvent(sYear.value);
```

You probably want to do this instead:

```
onChange = function () {
    return Puma.selectEvent(sYear.value);
};
```